# Facebook check several events in one call

Tags: php, facebook, events

I'm working on a event schedule and want to know if there is a way to check multiple events without adding them to you private follow list in Facebook.

I've 2000 events that need to be checked and want to get the right information of the events.

I use now this way. 
I check event on facebook event id, i add this event to my private event list on Facebook and after that i can get every information of this event.

I like to hear from you, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is currently no way for normal 3rd-party apps to access user or page events via API.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/events:

> This edge is only available to a limited number of approved apps. Unapproved apps querying this edge will receive an empty data set in response. You cannot request access to this edge at this time.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/events:

> This is a restricted edge. You cannot request access at this time.